# Google Scripts - Adding Days to Date -

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I ask for your help because I understand very little about programming! ;-(

I have a google form where customers sign up.
Each contact who registers is added to the associated sheet indicating the date and time of registration (column A)

I would like to know if with a script, associated with sending the form, we could have this value added to column J:
**REGISTRATION DATE + 7 days**

[image]

Thank you all for your valuable help!

Comment: Post some code. That will be helpful

Comment: why don't you just do =registrationdate+7 in column J I don't get it?

Comment: The data is automatically synchronized on a mysql database. If I enter this formula "= A2 + 7". The problem occurs when on the blank lines - without registration date - in column J I always have a number and this creates problems with synchronization on the database.

Cell J should remain empty until a new registration occurs in column A.
I hope I explained myself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try writing the date when submitting the form. Use the [Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) Trigger to run this function:

```
function newRow() {

  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your sheet Id");
  var sheet = sprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  //Gets the current date and adds 7 days to it
  var date = new Date();
  var value = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate()+7));

  //"10" is the J column
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 10).setValue(value);

  }
```

References:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow)
- [DateField](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/date-field)

Comment: thank you very much for your help.
Do I need to activate this script from the module or directly from the sheet?
Then I have to apply the trigger

Comment: You have to attach this script to your Form, save it and follow the steps from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to create the Trigger but using 'on Form submit' as event.

Comment: Fantastic, it works great. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider accepting my answer, so others will see it works without looking into the comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a need to use Google Apps Script here. Just use the formulas to check for blanks in the date range

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),"",A2:A + 7));
```

The formula checks if the cell is blank and outputs an empty string if this condition evaluates to true. If the condition is false it increments the date by 7 days. 
Note that after applying the formula to the range, you may get what looks like numbers in results column (see below). These are valid dates that you can get to show correctly by applying date formatting to the column.

[image: Dates before formatting]

[image: Dates after formatting]